# Unable to locate element in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, frame

I'm trying to locate an element using python selenium, and have the following code:

```
zframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/frameset/frameset/frame[5]")
driver.switch_to.frame(zframe)
findByXpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/label[3]").click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='awdType']")
```

I'm getting the error that:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='awdType']"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=59.0.3071.115)

Any ideas why it may not be able to locate this element? I used the exact xpath by copying it and also switched frames. Thanks!

Comment: Which site are you crawling ?

Comment: The error `Unable to locate element` says it all. Either the `xpath` of the element is incorrect or element is not present/visible. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because `awdType` is loaded by ajax or jquery.
You should use [selenium Waits.](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) There is two type of waits explicit and implicit.*Avoid using implicit wait.*

```
# Explicit wait example
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'awdType')))
```

OR

```
# implicit wait example
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='awdType']")
```

Comment: How can you conclude `awdType is loaded by ajax or jquery` ? Thanks

Comment: This item is not rendered into the dom when your script reached at element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='awdType']")

Comment: From this, I'm getting the error that "WebDriverWait" is undefined even when I include the above header to import expected_conditions as EC

Comment: Ok, I added headers to fix that problem. However now when I run it, I'm getting this error:

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

Sarahs-MacBook-Pro-3:python shynds23$