# I get this error when I try to find an element by css selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="user_email"]
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDw6u.png)

```
url = 'https://candidature.1337.ma/users/sign_in'
r = requests.head(url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    browser= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\myrdp\\Desktop\\pool_jdid\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe" ,options=options)
    browser.maximize_window()
    email_box = 'none'
    pass_box = 'none'
    while email_box == 'none' and pass_box == 'none':
        browser.get("https://candidature.1337.ma/users/sign_in")
        email_box=browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="user_email"]
    ''')
        email_box.send_keys(user)
        pass_box=browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="user_password"]''')
        pass_box.send_keys(password)
        login_button=browser.find_element_by_name("commit")
    login_button.submit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to locate element in Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476419/unable-to-locate-element-in-python-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wait for that element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

email_box = WebDriverWait(10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'user_email')))
```